# How to recover undelete deleted file dhcpd.leases file?

Tags: linux, testdisk

I made a back up of DHCP but when i unstinalled it the back up was removed.

How can i recover dhcpd.leases

Example  /var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases

its on /dev/mapper/vg_server-lv_root

i did do a locate dhcpd.leases no results were found

OS Centos 6

Thank you in advance.

I tried testdisk on the logical drive but it would not work with /dev/mapper/vg_server-lv_root

Comment: If you do not have a backup of the file then there is no way to recover it.

Comment: undelete just disappered in compouter exisstance?

Comment: for text files with known unique contents/syntax, you can try your luck with strings and grep, for example `strings -n 32 -w /dev/device | grep -C 1000 -F 'hardware ethernet'`

Comment: undelete has always been dodgy on multi-user systems.  Try `photorec`.